# Managing shown buttons, labels and other controlls

Tags: vb.net, controls

Whenever I want to hide some buttons because of a condition I go like this

```
button1.visible = false
```

So say I start up form-X and on the load I check if this user has the required conditions. Is this user a member of this company? yes? ok well then you can see this button1 and this label changes.

In this form-X you can remove yourself from that company. Now I need to put ANOTHER condition to check if the buttons are allowed to stay there or not whenever company is removed from the userslist.

The problem is not me putting it visible or invisible, but the way the code looks when you see several buttons going off or on at certain conditions doesn't look good. Also when a condition changes, I need go about all the code at different locations and adjust it.

Isn't there a way to handle all these conditions at one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend making a single private method that hides and shows all the controls based on the current conditions. You could call it something like SetupForm, for instance. Then, just call that method everywhere any of the conditions change.

Comment: Ye I geuss that this would be the option then. Was just scared that I would go through to much code and it would slow things down.